# ejs not conneting with css file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am working with simple express node js But my css file does not link with ejs both are the same folder shown in below picture. and also `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/website"))` is here

I have searched on google but the problem still there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following css folder should be in a public folder..

and in express your command should be:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

and your link tag in html should be as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/regPage.css">
```